# why just the last input is storage?

Tags: printing, java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class error{

    private static class punto{
        int x, y;
    }
    private static class lados{
        punto inicio = new punto(); 

        public lados(punto inicio1){
            inicio=inicio1;

        }
        public punto getInicio(){
            return inicio;
        }
        public void setInicio(punto inicio){
            this.inicio = inicio;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[]args){
        Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
        punto inicio = new punto();
        lados arreglo[] = new lados[100];

        for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
            inicio.x = leer.nextInt();
            inicio.y = leer.nextInt();
            arreglo[i] = new lados(inicio);
        }

        for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
            System.out.println(arreglo[i].getInicio().x);
            System.out.println(arreglo[i].getInicio().y);
        }
    }
}
```

what am I doing wrong?
I want to storage ponits(x,y) in an index on an array
but just the last input is storaged in all index...
maybe there is other way to do what I want to do, if someone share it I'd love it.

input:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

output:

```
5
6
5
6
5
6
```

expected output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Comment: Your code looks OK at first glance.  Can you be more specific about the error you are getting?  What does the output look like and what did you expect it to look like?  What does the input consist of?

Comment: I edited it with more info, I hope you can help me

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the same `inicio` instance in all `lados` instances you are creating :

```
 for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
            inicio.x = leer.nextInt();
            inicio.y = leer.nextInt();
            arreglo[i] = new lados(inicio);
  }
```

You should create a new instance of punto for each lados if you want that the information to not be overwritten at each iteration.
Try that :

```
 for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
            inicio = new punto()
            inicio.x = leer.nextInt();
            inicio.y = leer.nextInt();
            arreglo[i] = new lados(inicio);
  }
```

By convention, classes should begin by an uppercase letter : Punto, Lados, etc...